# AngularJS Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] -- noob here

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-injector

I'm not using ngRoute or any Angular service that needs to be injected. And I'm injecting my own module and controller as, I think, needed. But still getting the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=try&p1=Error%3A%20%…2015%2520experiments%2Fangulartrial%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A163)
at angular.min.js:6
at angular.min.js:40
at r (angular.min.js:7)
at g (angular.min.js:39)
at db (angular.min.js:43)
at c (angular.min.js:20)
at Bc (angular.min.js:21)
at ge (angular.min.js:19)
at angular.min.js:315
at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:189)
```

Code:
Index.html:

```
<html ng-app="try" lang="En">
<head>
    <title>Learn Angular 1.5</title>
    <!-- <script src="./js/lib/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script> -->
    <script src='./js/lib/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src='app.js'></script>
    <script src='./js/app/blog-list.module.js'></script>
    <script src='./js/app/blog-list.component.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class='' ng-controller = 'BlogListController'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module ('try', ['blogList'])
    //This works when I declare the controller right here
    // .controller('BlogListController', function(){
    //  console.log("Hello");
    // })
```

blog-list.module.js

```
'use strict';
//simply declare the module here 
angular.module('blogList', [
    //inject dependencies
    'BlogListController'
    ]);
```

blog-list.component.js

```
 //declare the controllers, components etc on the module here 
angular.module('blogList')
    .controller('BlogListController', function(){
        console.log("Hello");
    });
```

Comment: don't inject `BlogListController` controller as a dependency.. removing that from `blogList` module will fix the issue

Comment: you should just remove `BlogListController` from `blogList`

Answer (score 1):

Issue is here `BlogListController` as a depdendency,

```
angular.module('blogList', [
    //inject dependencies
    'BlogListController'
    ]);
```

Change it as,

```
angular.module('blogList', []);
```

Remove the BlogListController from the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're HTML is not using the 'blogList' module. Change it to:

```
<html ng-app="blogList" lang="En">
 ...
</html>
```

Also you don't inject your 'BlogListController' when declaring the module. The array is meant for dependency injection of external modules that your newly created module would require to run

(ex: ngRoute is a popular module that doesn't come 'out of box' and has to be included via dependency injection)

Comment: The index.html page is using the the `blogList` module, as a dependency of the `try` module. But +1 for pointing out that the problem was with injecting the controller into the module that already declared it.